# TimescaleDB: How to avoid deadlocks on hypertables with a compression AND retention policy during SELECT?

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb, database-deadlocks

I am getting deadlocks from postgres occasionally when attempting to execute a `SELECT` query on a hypertable with both a compression and retention policy.

From the logs, it looks like the deadlock is occuring because the retention policy is kicking off in a job at the same time a `SELECT` query is executing.

Here's a sanitized snippet from the postgres logs:

```
2023-08-16T15:02:21.680047 [14-1] pid=235144,user=user,db=test,app=[unknown],client=9.9.9.9 ERROR:  deadlock detected",

2023-08-16T15:02:21.680244 [14-2] pid=235144,user=user,db=test,app=[unknown],client=9.9.9.9 DETAIL:  Process 235144 waits for ShareLock on transaction 6376925; blocked by process 252148.",

2023-08-16T15:02:21.680315 [14-3]  Process 252148 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 2999269 of database 16413; blocked by process 235144.",

2023-08-16T15:02:21.680392 [14-4]  Process 235144: select coalesce(max(i.item_sequence),0) from items i where i.item_time >= now() and i.item_category_id = $1",

2023-08-16T15:02:21.680432 [14-5]  Process 252148: CALL _timescaledb_internal.policy_retention()",

2023-08-16T15:02:21.680465 [14-6] pid=235144,user=user,db=test,app=[unknown],client=9.9.9.9 HINT:  See server log for query details.",

2023-08-16T15:02:21.680493 [14-7] pid=235144,user=user,db=test,app=[unknown],client=9.9.9.9 CONTEXT:  while locking tuple (0,158) in relation \"dimension_slice\"",

2023-08-16T15:02:21.680526 [14-8] pid=235144,user=user,db=test,app=[unknown],client=9.9.9.9 STATEMENT:  select coalesce(max(i.item_sequence),0) from items i where i.item_time >= now() and i.item_category_id = $1",
```

Basics of the hypertable in question:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items (
    item_time bigint NOT NULL,
    item_category_id varchar NOT NULL,
    item_sequence int NOT NULL
);

create index on items (item_category_id, item_time asc, item_sequence asc);
```

With the following data retention policy that deletes data older than, say, 2 days and checks it every 2 hours:

```
-- retention policy to drop content older than 2 days
SELECT add_retention_policy('items', BIGINT '172800000'); -- 2 days = 172800000 milliseconds

-- alter the retention policy job to drop old data every 2 hours instead of the default of once a day
SELECT alter_job(job_id, schedule_interval => INTERVAL '2 hours') FROM timescaledb_information.jobs WHERE proc_name = 'policy_retention' AND hypertable_name = 'items';
```

...and a similar compression policy:

```
ALTER TABLE items SET (timescaledb.compress, timescaledb.compress_segmentby = 'item_category_id');

-- we compress data that is 4 hours old
SELECT add_compression_policy('items', BIGINT '14400000');

-- Alter the new compression job so that it kicks off every 2 hours instead of the default of once a day, so we can compress old data quickly
SELECT alter_job(job_id, schedule_interval => INTERVAL '2 hours') FROM timescaledb_information.jobs WHERE proc_name = 'policy_compression' AND hypertable_name = 'items';
```

If I'm interpreting everything above correctly, it is maybe possible that the two locks in question are between the retention policy job kicking off, dropping older chunks, followed by the `SELECT` statement *maybe* causing the entire table to be scanned and triggering decompression - which results in another lock?

I would have thought the `where i.item_time >= now() and i.item_category_id = $1` would have caused only the latest chunk to be checked??

I feel like I am missing something fundamental.

There ARE alternatives, from having the retention policy kick off less often to storing the latest `item_sequence` in a continuous aggregate (maybe?), but I am not sure what the simplest option is.

Comment: It seems a bug in the latest version.

I see a related issue on dimension_slice that seems exactly the same case:

https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/5996

Comment: Yes. I opened a ticket and talked with some of the TS team on slack, and they ended up confirming it as a bug.  Will wait for resolution before closing this out. Also experimenting with workarounds in the meantime that I may add here for others.